# Find numbers in a file and change their value with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with some data in it but there are a bunch of annoying numbers that are less than one which I wanted to just change to 1 instead of manually doing it. I was wondering how you would do this in perl.

I tried using something like this

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/$& < 1 ? $&=1 : $&/g' file
```

This basically just finds all numbers and then checks if they are less then 1. If so then set it to 1 and if not leave it alone. Unfortunately, it will not allow $&=1 to happen since it is a readonly. Is there something else in perl that would achieve this effect?
Example input:

```
this 1 is a 7 file that
has 0.5 some numbers 4
that are 0.3 less 0.1 than 0.9 
one as you see 1.1
```

Output:

```
this 1 is a 7 file that
has 1 some numbers 4
that are 1 less 1 than 1 
one as you see 1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just match the numbers that are less than one.. and replace with `1`:

```
perl -pe 's/\b0\.\d+/1/g' file
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rL7dX9/2)

Comment: And for bonus points: `echo -0.7 | perl -pe 's/\b0\.\d+/1/g'` prints `-1`. The OP's sample input doesn't contain negative numbers, but a robust solution should probably handle them. Of course, if we go that route, -1 should also be converted to 1, and the OP didn't mention that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\b0\.\d+\b
```

You can try this.Replace by `1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/29